# Can't change default theme of Magento 2.2.4

Tags: magento

I am trying to change the default theme for a fresh install of Magento 2.2.4 and the following error was thrown on Save. "Something went wrong while saving this configuration: Area is already set".

Comment: Keep on eye on this thread: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14968

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known bug in Magento 2.2.4: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14968

Please refer to the issue on Github on how to solve your problem. You'll find the fix in this commit: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/0dec988872e175e568c2bf4bb29548ab7a4698e5

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 doesn't do hotfix releases, unfortunately.
However, they've released an official patch over here: https://magento.com/tech-resources/download (search for MAGETWO-93036).

Apply this patch by using below command

patch -p1 < m2-hotfixes/EE-MAGETWO-93036-2018-07-02-07-07-16.patch.

After applying mention patch then It works perfectly.

Comment: hi @SWapnil, can you explain me how did you applied this patch?

Comment: 1) Connect with a server through SSH details

for eg. ssh user@host -pXYZ

XYZ- (port number)

2) Go to the Magento root directory then perform below command

patch -p1 < m2-hotfixes/EE-MAGETWO-93036-2018-07-02-07-07-16.patch

That's it.
Note:  Make sure patch command is installed in your server.